# Better structure for Looking up booleans for an index?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This is a bit nitpicking and I might have overlooked something simple

Sometimes I have some integers and have to be able to lookup whether they're true or false. I've always solved this by using an Dictionary<int,bool> , inserting a true and just using ContainsKey to see if something is true (it's false by default.)

But it doesn't seem like an elegant solution to insert a bool that isn't even used :) What's structure would you recommend for this? Lookup performance being primary and insertions secondary (but important)

Some nice (LINQ) syntax for having a bunch of indices and returning items that are not contained would be a bonus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [`HashSet<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to hold the "true" integers and use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) to search the collection.  With this approach you store just the data you need and you get the same O(1) performance you are currently getting with the dictionary.

Comment: Assusing all "int" have a value, and there is not a 3rd state of "unknown"

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aray of ints.

Set array[position] = 1 if true or = 0 for false.

Lookup is done in O(1) and insertion you already have it. You declare the array as long as you need.

It is not the most memeory economical solution. In .NET 2.0 you don't have HashSet.

Or option number two you can use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)